# Difference between differencing data and removing trend line for stationarity

Tags: arima, data-transformation, stationarity, seasonality, trend

In reference to making data stationary for Arima:

Is there a difference between subtracting a best fit line from data, and a first order difference?

Or, subtracting an exponential fit from data, and performing a second difference operation?

Also, if I decompose data by subtracting a best fit line (trend), say I then find the frequency of a seasonal pattern. Say I split the data into columns according to that seasonal frequency, and calculate and subtract the mean of each column. I think this is a way to elliminate the seasonal pattern from the data.

Is this the same as a seasonal difference operation in seasonal Arima (S-Arima)?

Should I do these operations before performing an Arima, or are the difference operations in Arima and S-Arima meant to produce the same effect?

Comment: By writing down the explicit expression of each operation, you will see these are not the same. For example, you will see that differencing creates unit-root MA processes while subtracting deterministic trends does not. (Think of the concept *overdifferencing*.) Moreover, second-order differencing is related to removing quadratic trends, not exponential trends.

Comment: I understand these operations are different mathematically, but every reference I read just writes : "Remove the trend by doing this operation," without explaining why one operation is better than another. When would it be better to subtract a trend manually versus complete a difference operation? Same question applies for seasonal patterns.

Comment: Depends on what you assume the data generating process to be. If your series is a cumulative sum, difference it. If it is not, subtract a deterministic trend.

Comment: this last comment supports my criticisms of auto.arima as all that it does is to apply differencing to non-stationary data while ignoring detrending via deterministic structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s there a difference between subtracting a best fit line from data, and a first order difference? YES .. actually do this and you will get different results . Your real question is How do I decide which approach to take ?

Or, subtracting an exponential fit from data, and performing a second difference operation?

same answer as above ...

Also, if I decompose data by subtracting a best fit line (trend), say I then find the frequency of a seasonal pattern. Say I split the data into columns according to that seasonal frequency, and calculate and subtract the mean of each column. I think this is a way to elliminate the seasonal pattern from the data.

What I think you are doing here is adding SEASONAL DUMMIES as input series to an SARMAX model https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf

Is this the same as a seasonal difference operation in seasonal Arima (S-Arima)?

no . The approach you detailed here is to allow for DETERMINISTIC SEASONAL STRUCTURE as compared to SEASONAL DIFFERENCING. Again your real question is which one do i choose and how do I choose it ?

TOO VAGUE TO EVEN TRY TO ANSWER .

Should I do these operations before performing an Arima, or are the difference operations in Arima and S-Arima meant to produce the same effect?

The approach to resolving these opportunities requires 1) a data set and more importantly software/procedures to approach this problem in a holistic way where alternative approaches are tried and evaluated culminating a best/optimal strategy/model for this data set. In other words you customize the solution to the data as the data knows what is going on .. you just have to allow it to talk (so to speak !  .

https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf details this tour de force which can be programmed in many different languages ..it just might take some time .

By the way I hope my New York Approach ( i.e. straight/honest and direct) doesn't betray my roots ....

Comment: Okay, this is helping. 

So, sometimes you can do decomposition and put the remaining data (data minus trend and deterministic seasonal structure) through an Arima. 

And, sometimes you can do seasonal and non seasonal differencing. 

I need examples of when to do each. When does decomposing fail, and when does differencing fail?

Thank you so much! (I'm from NY, and I prefer it)

Comment: not so much .. in fact not at all . what you want to do is to ultimately simultaneously do  this in a seamless way NOT sequentially as tests of significance vanish .

Comment: I am not from NY , I am from Brooklyn ! . regards . again if you are tired typing (as I am ) , I speak a lot better in helping you to understand some of the intricacies not discussed  by your simplistic reference.